# Как получить ошибку загрузки плеера youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

у меня получается обработать успешную загрузку плеера youtube с помощью `.onload`, но когда у плеера происходит ошибка и он не загружается, то `.onerror` не работает. Хотел бы очень узнать, как можно как-то обработать ошибку загрузки

Мой код:

```
bgvideo.onload = () => {
    console.log('nice')
}
bgvideo.onerror = () => {
  console.log('bad')
}
```

Comment: Что такое `bgvideo`?

Comment: @andreymal  Это iframe, импортированный через query selector. (background video)